# Grafana dashboard with collectd for prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, collectd

Does anyone have created dashboard for Grafana with collectd and Prometheus.
All dashboard on grafana site for Prometheus isn't created for collectd collector.

I created my, but I can't to include everything data.

Thank you !

Comment: did you find the dashboard, i'm also searching for dashboards

Comment: No, I didn't ! :(

Comment: You are looking for how to configure/setup collectd with prometheus and get metrics on grafana or you grafana dashboard with all collectd metrics loaded as graphs?

Comment: I need grafana dashboard with all collectd metrics loaded as graph. Not all, but most popular is ok, disk, network, cpu, memory, nginx, apache, mysql etc.

Comment: I'm looking for this as well I found https://github.com/Naugrimm/promql-examples 
 for query example but I'm having a hard time converting these queries into rate queries for graphing.